# need help to understand a Perl script

Tags: perl, protocols

I'm working on serial communication with a multimeter VA18B that uses PC Link data protocol.
The problem is that I cannot find any documentation for this protocol. The only thing I've got is a Perl script that decodes the frame (as far as I know, the frame consists of 14 bytes). Unfortunately the script is pretty complicated for someone who don't know Perl at all.

Can someone explain the below code?

```
sub decode_bin_str {
    my ($AC, $DC, $auto, $unknown1,
        $minus, $digi1, $dot1, $digi2, $dot2, $digi3, $dot3, $digi4,
        $micro, $unknown2, $kilo, $diode_test,
        $milli, $percent, $mega, $cont_check,
        $unknown3, $ohm, $rel, $hold,
        $amp, $volt, $hz, $unknown4,
        $min, $unknown5, $celsius, $max) = shift =~
           /^(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.{7})(.)(.{7})(.)(.{7})(.)(.{7})
        (.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.) *$/x;

    my %digi = (
        "1111101" => 0,
        "0000101" => 1,
        "1011011" => 2,
        "0011111" => 3,
        "0100111" => 4,
        "0111110" => 5,
        "1111110" => 6,
        "0010101" => 7,
        "1111111" => 8,
        "0111111" => 9,
    );

    my $val = ($minus ? "-" : "") . $digi{$digi1} . ($dot1 ? "." : "") .
                    $digi{$digi2} . ($dot2 ? "." : "") .
                    $digi{$digi3} . ($dot3 ? "." : "") .
                    $digi{$digi4};

    my $flags = join(" ", $AC         ? "AC"         : (),
                  $DC         ? "DC"         : (),
                  $auto       ? "auto"       : (),
                  $diode_test ? "diode_test" : (),
                  $cont_check ? "cont_check" : (),
                  $rel        ? "rel"        : (),
                  $hold       ? "hold"       : (),
                  $min        ? "min"        : (),
                  $max        ? "max"        : ());

    my $unit = ($micro   ? "u"   : "") .
           ($kilo    ? "k"   : "") .
           ($milli   ? "m"   : "") .
           ($mega    ? "M"   : "") .
           ($percent ? "%"   : "") .
           ($ohm     ? "Ohm" : "") .
           ($amp     ? "A"   : "") .
           ($volt    ? "V"   : "") .
           ($hz      ? "Hz"  : "") .
           ($celsius ? "C"   : "");

    $val, $flags, $unit;
}
```

Comment: A line by line explanation of an entire subroutine isn't likely to be of much help to anyone except you. If you're dealing with Perl (note the spelling, it is not called 'PERL') then learn Perl. It has a comprehensive manual (and that code doesn't appear to use anything outside the core language). If a particular part is causing you problems, then a more specific question is likely to be worthwhile asking here.

Comment: @Quentin I don't really need a line by line explanation. I think that J-16SDiZ's answer will be enough to "decode" this protocol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This function take a binary (0/1) string. The regex is a pattern:

```
/^(.)(.).....(.{7})......
```

`(.)` mean one charactor, `(.{7})` means 7 of them.

```
my ($AC, $DC, $auto, $unknown1.......= shift =~ /^(.)(.)(.)(.) ....
```

means, given `1011.....` as input, `AC` would be `1`, `DC` would be `0` and `auto`/`unknown1` will be `1`.

Digit1/2/3/4 are the digits, `dot1`...`dot4` tells where you put the decimal point.

`auto`/`diode_test`/.. say the mode..

`ohm`/`volt`/.... say which unit you are using.

The rest is pretty easy.